# Merging two dataframes with additional business rules

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, merge

I have two Pandas dataframes, and I would like to match them up by ID and find the differences in their dates if a match can be found. An example of my first dataframe is:

```
ID Date_A
=========
1  01012023
1  02012023
1  03012023
2  02152023
3  02012023
3  04012023
```

My second dataframe looks like:

```
ID Date_B
=========
1  01112023
1  03112023
3  05012023
```

I am trying to perform `pd.merge()` on the two dataframes to receive a result like the following. Notice that `Date_B` must be merged so it comes chronologically after the next earliest occurrence of `Date_A`.

```
ID Date_A   Date_B
==================
1  01012023 01112023
1  02012023 03112023
1  03012023 
2  02152023
3  02012023 05012023
3  04012023
```

I am trying to perform `pd.merge()` operations on these two data frames, but instead of including just 3 entries of `Date_B`, it copies the `Date_B` occurrences for all records. Each `Date_A` and `Date_B` record can only be used once.

Is there a good way to achieve this desired result? I am struggling to find a method to achieve this. Thank you!

Comment: programmatically, it's quite hard to join by ID because the ID column doesn't uniquely identify each pair. We are meant to infer the pairs, but I'm guessing we are meant to assume that ones that occur in the same month are part of the same pair?

Comment: They won't necessarily occur in the same month @MarkHill but assume that you can join any Date_B to the earliest Date_A. Date_B must occur after Date_A. I realize this is a non-trivial task

Comment: is the format mmddyyyy?

Comment: Yes @AtanasAtanasov that is correct

Comment: how big are the data-frames you want to merge?
what is the maximum distance in days between Date_A and  Date_B?
There is a  solution that comes to my mind but it will be very long and inefficient probably

Comment: @AtanasAtanasov both data frames only have about 1000 rows. There is no maximum distance in days, but Date_B must come after Date_A. If there is only a Date_B for a given ID, then there will be no associated Date_A. I don't mind if it is less efficient, as Ik this isn't a straight-forward problem

Comment: 325 there is an issue with the rule you stated for ID 3 and ID 1. With ID1, the second join occurs on the later option. On ID 3, it's on the earlier one

Comment: why is `05012023` matching `02012023` and not `04012023` for ID 3? This is not consistent with ID 1 in which `03112023` matches `03012023`, not `02012023`

Comment: @MarkHill My mistake, I've fixed the OP

Comment: @mozway My mistake, I've fixed the OP

Comment: I picked the wrong one 

Comment: You might want to edit your question using a YYYY-MM-DD format for your dates, this doesn't change the logic and will make it much more explicit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC, you need a [`merge_asof`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.merge_asof.html), combined with a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html):

```
# ensure datetime
df1['Date_A'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date_A'], format='%m%d%Y')
df2['Date_B'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date_B'], format='%m%d%Y')

df1.merge(
 pd.merge_asof(df2.sort_values(by='Date_B'),
               df1.sort_values(by='Date_A'),
               left_on='Date_B', right_on='Date_A', by='ID',
              ), how='left'
)
```

Or post-processing to remove duplicates:

```
# ensure datetime
df1['Date_A'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date_A'], format='%m%d%Y')
df2['Date_B'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Date_B'], format='%m%d%Y')

out = (
pd.merge_asof(df1.sort_values(by='Date_A').reset_index(),
               df2.sort_values(by='Date_B'),
               left_on='Date_A', right_on='Date_B', by='ID',
               direction='forward'
              )
  .set_index('index')
  .assign(Date_B=lambda d: d['Date_B'].mask(d.duplicated(['ID', 'Date_B'],
                                                         keep='last')))
  .sort_index()
)
```

Output:

```
  ID     Date_A     Date_B
0  1 2023-01-01 2023-01-11
1  1 2023-02-01        NaT
2  1 2023-03-01 2023-03-11
3  2 2023-02-15        NaT
4  3 2023-02-01        NaT
5  3 2023-04-01 2023-05-01
```

*Note that your output is slightly different as you're mapping the latest vs earliest date for ID1/ID3.*

mapping on the first using `keep='first'`:

```
      ID     Date_A     Date_B
index                         
0      1 2023-01-01 2023-01-11
1      1 2023-02-01 2023-03-11
2      1 2023-03-01        NaT
3      2 2023-02-15        NaT
4      3 2023-02-01 2023-05-01
5      3 2023-04-01        NaT
```

Comment: Date_B must occur *after* Date_A. What would I need to do to adjust your solution?

Comment: @325 this is already the case no? Just use my second approach with `keep='first'`, not `keep='last'`